# Can $(\log\log m)/(\log\log n)$ be rational?

Tags: nt.number-theory

If $m, n$ are two different positive integers, is it true that the ratio $\displaystyle \frac{\log\log m}{\log\log n}$ is necessarily irrational?  By $\log$ I mean the logarithm in base $e$ (not base $10$).
I guess it is irrational, but I don't know why?

Comment: What about (10^(10^1))/(10^(10^2))?

Comment: Here I meant :

log n = log_e n

Comment: I have made some typographical and copyediting changes.  If I have changed the meaning of anything or otherwise introduced any errors, I apologize, and you can roll back the edits in the edit window.

Answer (score 10):

I'll assume you mean the natural logarithm.  The condition that $\log \log m = q \log \log n$ where $q = \frac{a}{b}$ is rational is equivalent to the condition $(\log m)^b = (\log n)^a$.  If $m \neq n$ then $a \neq b$ and this condition cannot be satisfied if $\log m$ is a rational multiple of $\log n$ because $\log n$ is transcendental by [Lindemann-Weierstrass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

If $\log m$ is not a rational multiple of $\log n$, then this condition cannot be satisfied if one assumes [Schanuel's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture), since then $\mathbb{Q}(n, m \log n, \log m)$ would have transcendence degree $1$.  So this is likely to be true but out of reach of current technology (although I don't know enough about transcendence theory to say this with any authority).

Comment: hi
i did not convinced with the second part of answer
tnx

Comment: Do you understand the statement of Schanuel's conjecture?

Comment: In case $\log m$ is not a rational multiple of $\log n$, it is known (from the theory of linear forms in logs) that 1, $\log m$ and $\log n$ are *linearly* independent over the field of algebraic numbers, and it is hypothesized (long time ago) that they are in fact *algebraically* independent. The latter is implied by Schanuel's conjecture.

Comment: @asd: The overall content of Qiaochu's answer, unless I am misreading it (I am not an expert), is that the answer to your question is almost certainly "yes, it is irrational", but that a proof of this fact does not exist, and is rather a long-standing conjecture.  @Qiaochu: I am not an expert.  I guess your parenthetical disclaimer means that maybe OP's question is provably true even without Schanuel's conjecture?

Comment: @Theo: yes.  The parenthetical comment should be read as "likely to be (true but out of reach of current technology)" rather than "(likely to be true) but out of reach of current technology."